# Pick particular match keyword from one column and paste it on last column-Linux

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, text

I have data in CSV, where 3rd column contain exact 5 digit number. Need to copy this number and paste in last column.

```
2020-05-19_19:03:07,210,HR051919040_to_17622_is_ok.   
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,MP051919032700_to_Average_95840_is_ok.   
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,   
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,RJ0515_to_System__to_66638_is_nok.
```

Output:

```
2020-05-19_19:03:07,210,HR051919040_to_17622_is_ok.,17622   
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,MP051919032700_to_Average_95840_is_ok.,95840   
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,,   
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,RJ0515_to_System__to_66638_is_nok.,66638
```

I tried to use sed to search for 5 digit number but it is not working as it has character as well.

```
sed -n '/\b[0-9]\{5\}\b/p'
```

Comment: The question is interesting, but just too hard to read for further generations of readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -E 's/_([0-9]{5})_(.*)$/_\1_\2,\1/' file
2020-05-19_19:03:07,210,HR051919040_to_17622_is_ok.,17622
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,MP051919032700_to_Average_95840_is_ok.,95840
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,RJ0515_to_System__to_66638_is_nok.,66638
```

- `_([0-9]{5})_` matches five digits between the `_`
- `(.*)$` matches til the end of line
- `_\1_\2,\1` restores the original part (`_\1_\2`) and then appends `,\1`

---

Your sample data in the question had trailing space characters. If this also is the case in your live data use

```
sed -E 's/_([0-9]{5})_(.*\.)[[:blank:]]+$/_\1_\2,\1/' file
```

instead to strip trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It was very helpful as I was stuck on this from morning.

Comment: That would find 5 digit numbers surrounded by `_` anywhere in the line, not just in the 3rd field, and it wouldn't find 5 digit numbers at the start or end of the 3rd field. Are those both OK? It's also worth saying that it requires a sed that supports `-E`, e.g. GNU sed, but won't work with all POSIX seds.

Comment: @EdMorton There is currently nothing in the question which would indicate that the pattern won't match the input (but yes, it won't work for the cases you mention). Without a full specification of the input it's hard to prove the correctness of any solution (the 3rd field could include `\,` for instance as part of the text).

Answer (score 4):

You could use awk's `match` - something like

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} match($3,/_[0-9]{5}_/){$(NF+1) = substr($3,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)} 1' file.csv
2020-05-19_19:03:07,210,HR051919040_to_17622_is_ok.,17622
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,MP051919032700_to_Average_95840_is_ok.,95840
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,RJ0515_to_System__to_66638_is_nok.,66638
```

Including the leading and trailing underscores in the match and then trimming them with the `substr` ensures you don't match a sequence of 5 digits elsewhere in the field.

Comment: Thanks!!! this is also correct.

Comment: That's less fragile and more portable than the currently accepted sed solutions but still wouldn't find 5 digit numbers at the start or end of the 3rd field. Is that OK?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -nle 'print "$_,",/_(\d{5})_/' ex
2020-05-19_19:03:07,210,HR051919040_to_17622_is_ok.,17622
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,MP051919032700_to_Average_95840_is_ok.,95840
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,,
2020-05-19_19:03:07,200,RJ0515_to_System__to_66638_is_nok.,66638
```

For each line in input    `perl -nle`

- print it and a "," `print "$_,"`
- and also the number if present in the line `/_(\d{5})_/`

(we may want to tune the regular expression do deal extra constrains)